# How to change a Dynamic Resource value via xaml (Triggers for example)

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, dynamicresource

for example, I have a style for the element and with the trigger I want to change specific resource

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Tree:MyListBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Property}" Value="ItemSelected">
           <Setter Property="MydinamicResourceKey" Value="NewValue"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Change resource is impossible. So to dyhnamic changing props is possible via 2 ways : DataTrigger from Microsoft.Expression.Interactions (http://sshumakov.com/2012/12/08/how-to-use-datatrigger-from-microsoft-expression-interactions/) or via custom binding (http://wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using VisualStateManager?

This is an idea from [Microsoft's ListBox Styles and Templates page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargeType="{x:Type Tree:MyListBox}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Tree:MyListBox}">
         <Border x:Name="Border">
           <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                 <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                 <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <Storyboard>
                       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="myUIElementName"
                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="myUIElementProperty">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{DynamicResource MyResourceKey}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                       </Storyboard>
                      </VisualState>
                     </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    .... more code here....
                  </Border>
                 </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
             </Style>
```

I have a [tutorial by Shawn Wildermuth bookmarked](http://wildermuth.com/2008/7/18/Animating_Brushes_with_ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames) on this type of Animation/Change - I still refer to it a lot.

Hopefully this is helpful and can get you going in the right direction.